# Material UI range slider in react js

Tags: reactjs

I am using material UI range slider for filtering product based on price range in my project. I want to console only last updated value on event change not all the values when dragging slider.

Comment: And the issue is?

Comment: I am getting all the values in console, I need only last updated value. Please help to find  the solution.

Comment: I'm assuming that you have added log on change event. And as you change value, you get all values. If my assumption is correct, you can create a variable and assign values on change and use the last value. If not, your question is very generic and needs more info.

Comment: I guess you need to use a debounce function

Answer (score 1):

All the values get consoled in the onChange function, however, if you want your state to be updated, the latest value will be where you leave your slider.

However, the following could also work for your case.

```
<Slider 
    onChange={ (e, val) => // set your state value here }  
    onChangeCommitted={(e, v) => //set your state here, this will only log when you ,leave the slider}
/>
```